# Kendo Grid serverFiltering filter jquery getting filter object null in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Please help me - why am I not getting filter request param in C# controller? I am not able to get all the filter data in controller side I have tried following:

[How to perform server side filtering on Kendo UI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144487/how-to-perform-server-side-filtering-on-kendo-ui-grid)

https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-do-server-side-filtering

HTML CODE

```
<div id="grid" class="kendo-grid mobilegrid"></div>
```

UI code with jQuery

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                            ServerOperation: true,
                            dataSource: {
                                transport: {
                                    read: {
                                        url: '/Partners/GetAllPartnersContactDetails1', //using jsfiddle echo service to simulate JSON endpoint
                                        type: "POST",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        async: true,
                                        //cache: false,
                                        contentType: 'application/json',
                                        data: function (e) {
                                            debugger;
                                            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                                            var $filter = new Array();
                                            grid.dataSource.filter(e.filter);
                                            console.log(e);
                                            return e;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                                        return kendo.stringify(data);
                                    }
                                },
                                schema: {
                                    data: function (result) {
                                        return result.Data;
                                    },
                                    total: function (result) {
                                        return result.Total;
                                    }
                                },
                                type: "json",
                                serverPaging: true,
                                serverFiltering: true,
                                pageSize: 25,
                            },
                            filterable: {
                                mode: 'row',
                                operators: {
                                    string: {
                                        contains: "contains"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageable: {
                                pageSizes: pageSizesArray,
                                numeric: false,
                                messages: {
                                    itemsPerPage: "@Resources.Shared.ItemsPerPage",
                                    display: "@Resources.Shared.PagingItemMsg",
                                    empty: "@Resources.Shared.NoData"
                                }
                                //refresh: true,
                            },
                            height: $(window).height() *85/100,
                            filterable: {
                                mode: "row",
                                operators: {
                                    string: {
                                        contains: 'containsStringFilter',
                                        eq: 'eqStringFilter',
                                        neq: 'neqStringFilter',
                                        isnull: 'isnullStringFilter',
                                        isnotnull: 'isnotnullStringFilter',
                                        isempty: 'isemptyStringFilter',
                                        isnotempty: 'isnotemptyStringFilter',
                                        startswith: 'startswithStringFilter',
                                        doesnotcontain: 'doesnotcontainStringFilter',
                                        endswith: 'endswithStringFilter',
                                        isnullorempty: 'isnulloremptyStringFilter',
                                        isnotnullorempty: 'isnotnulloremptyStringFilter',
                                    }
                                },
                                messages: {
                                    and: "And",
                                    or: "Or",
                                    info: "ShowItems"
                                }
                            },
                            dataBound: function () {
                                var filterCells = $(".k-filter-row").find("input");
                                filterCells.each(function (idx, cell) {
                                    if ($(cell).data("role") == "autocomplete") {
                                        var autocomplete = $(cell).data("kendoAutoComplete")
                                        autocomplete.setOptions({ noDataTemplate: "" })
                                    }
                                })
                            },
                            noRecords: {
                                template: '<h3>NoData</h3>'
                            },
                            sortable: true,
                            selectable: true,
                            reorderable: true,
                            columns: ColumnConfig,
                            columnMenu: {
                                messages: {
                                    columns: "Columns",
                                    filter: "Filter  ",
                                    sortAscending: "SortAscending",
                                    sortDescending: "SortDescending"
                                }
                            },
                            columnReorder: function (e) {
                                var that = this;
                                console.log(that.columns);
                                setTimeout(function () {

                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "/Common/ConfigureUserList/" + ListID,
                                        type: "POST",
                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                        data: JSON.stringify(that.columns),
                                        processData: false,
                                        success: function (objStatus) {}
                                    });
                                }, 5);

                            },
                            groupable: {
                                messages: {
                                    empty: "GroupingMsg"
                                }
                            }

                    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Controller code

```
 public JsonResult GetAllPartnersContactDetails1([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest filter, int pageSize, int skip, int? page = null, string filterField = null, string filterValue = null)
  {

            var objPartnersModel = new PartnersModel();
            var recordCount = objPartnersModel.GetAllPartnersContactDetails().Count();
            var dataSet = objPartnersModel.GetAllPartnersContactDetails().Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            DataSourceResult result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = dataSet,
                Total = recordCount
            };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

[image]
request param as follow
[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Just you need to add this line in dataSource` type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this it's working fine for me

Just you need to add this line for MVC application.

> `type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"`

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ServerOperation: true,
    dataSource: {
        type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/Partners/GetAllPartnersContactDetails1', //using jsfiddle echo service to simulate JSON endpoint
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                //cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: function(e) {
                    debugger;
                    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                    var $filter = new Array();
                    grid.dataSource.filter(e.filter);
                    console.log(e);
                    return e;
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                return kendo.stringify(data);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(result) {
                return result.Data;
            },
            total: function(result) {
                return result.Total;
            }
        },
        type: "json",
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 25,
    },
    filterable: {
        mode: 'row',
        operators: {
            string: {
                contains: "contains"
            }
        }
    },
    pageable: {
        pageSizes: pageSizesArray,
        numeric: false,
        messages: {
            itemsPerPage: "@Resources.Shared.ItemsPerPage",
            display: "@Resources.Shared.PagingItemMsg",
            empty: "@Resources.Shared.NoData"
        }
        //refresh: true,
    },
    height: $(window).height() * 85 / 100,
    filterable: {
        mode: "row",
        operators: {
            string: {
                contains: 'containsStringFilter',
                eq: 'eqStringFilter',
                neq: 'neqStringFilter',
                isnull: 'isnullStringFilter',
                isnotnull: 'isnotnullStringFilter',
                isempty: 'isemptyStringFilter',
                isnotempty: 'isnotemptyStringFilter',
                startswith: 'startswithStringFilter',
                doesnotcontain: 'doesnotcontainStringFilter',
                endswith: 'endswithStringFilter',
                isnullorempty: 'isnulloremptyStringFilter',
                isnotnullorempty: 'isnotnulloremptyStringFilter',
            }
        },
        messages: {
            and: "And",
            or: "Or",
            info: "ShowItems"
        }
    },
    dataBound: function() {
        var filterCells = $(".k-filter-row").find("input");
        filterCells.each(function(idx, cell) {
            if ($(cell).data("role") == "autocomplete") {
                var autocomplete = $(cell).data("kendoAutoComplete")
                autocomplete.setOptions({
                    noDataTemplate: ""
                })
            }
        })
    },
    noRecords: {
        template: '<h3>NoData</h3>'
    },
    sortable: true,
    selectable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    columns: ColumnConfig,
    columnMenu: {
        messages: {
            columns: "Columns",
            filter: "Filter  ",
            sortAscending: "SortAscending",
            sortDescending: "SortDescending"
        }
    },
    columnReorder: function(e) {
        var that = this;
        console.log(that.columns);
        setTimeout(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Common/ConfigureUserList/" + ListID,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(that.columns),
                processData: false,
                success: function(objStatus) {}
            });
        }, 5);

    },
    groupable: {
        messages: {
            empty: "GroupingMsg"
        }
    }

}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: this answer makes my day, what exactly I am looking for `type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"`

Comment: Glad to help you :)